# An error while using the License Maven Plugin in a multi module project

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

**Maven project structure**

I have a trivial multi module Maven project:

- `parent-project`

  - `child-project1` (`war`)
  - `child-project2` (`jar`)

`parent-project`'s `pom.xml` references both child projects in its `<modules>` section. Both child projects reference the parent in their `<parent>` sections.

`child-project1` depends on `child-project2` (it references it in the `<dependencies>` section).

**The problem**

I am trying to use the [License Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/license-maven-plugin/) on the `parent-project` to generates a file containing a list of all dependencies and their licenses:

```
mvn license:aggregate-add-third-party
```

I get an error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project child-project1: Could not resolve dependencies
for project ... child-project1 ... : Could not find artifact ... child-project2 ...
```

When I comment out the dependency of `child-project1` on `child-project2` the plugin works with no problem. So I can use the plugin, but I have to comment out the dependency each time I do it.

What is the problem? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that the `maven-license-plugin` by default looks in your local repository for the child artifacts. 
I suppose, your plugin configuration in the parent `pom.xml` looks like the following:

```
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- your own config goes here -->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

You have to install your multi-module project to your local Maven repository using

```
mvn install
```

After that, you run

```
mvn license:aggregate-add-third-party
```

again and the build will succeed.

If you configured an `<execution>` in your plugin, this will fail, since the `maven-license-plugin` by default binds to the `generate-resources` phase [[1]](http://mojo.codehaus.org/license-maven-plugin/aggregate-add-third-party-mojo.html) and this is always executed prior to `install` [[2]](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

Cheers,
PK